# Sorting maps within maps by value

Tags: sorting, groovy, dictionary

I'm trying to sort a map in Groovy that has maps as value. I want to iterate over the map and print out the values sorted by lastName and firstName values. So in the following example:

```
def m = 
[1:[firstName:'John', lastName:'Smith', email:'john@john.com'], 
2:[firstName:'Amy',  lastName:'Madigan', email:'amy@amy.com'], 
3:[firstName:'Lucy', lastName:'B',      email:'lucy@lucy.com'], 
4:[firstName:'Ella', lastName:'B',      email:'ella@ella.com'], 
5:[firstName:'Pete', lastName:'Dog',    email:'pete@dog.com']]
```

the desired results would be:

```
[firstName:'Ella', lastName:'B',      email:'ella@ella.com']
[firstName:'Lucy', lastName:'B',      email:'lucy@lucy.com']
[firstName:'Pete', lastName:'Dog',    email:'pete@dog.com']
[firstName:'Amy',  lastName:'Madigan', email:'amy@amy.com']
[firstName:'John', lastName:'Smith', email:'john@john.com']
```

I've tried m.sort{it.value.lastName&&it.value.firstName} and m.sort{[it.value.lastName, it.value.firstName]}. Sorting by m.sort{it.value.lastName} works but does not sort by firstName.

Can anybody help with this, much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9559309/581845). Could we mark them as duplicates and maybe merge them under a more general and descriptive title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
m.values().sort { a, b ->
  a.lastName <=> b.lastName ?: a.firstName <=> b.firstName
}
```